# Syntax error on token "(", ; expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am getting following error in 3rd line of my code:

> "Syntax error on token "(", ; expected"

```
public class ArrayFun1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
      public boolean Arrayfun(int[] A) {

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {

                    if (A[i] + A[j] + A[k] == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: You can't declare a method inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

You bare defining a method within the main method. Do it like this:

```
public class ArrayFun1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public boolean Arrayfun(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
                    if (A[i] + A[j] + A[k] == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As says on the comments, you cant create a method inside a method. You should change your code for something like:

```
public class ArrayFun1 {

public static boolean Arrayfun(int[] A) {

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {

                if (A[i] + A[j] + A[k] == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    int[] array = {2,3,4};
    ArrayFun1.Arrayfun(array);

  }

}
```